# ROI mask on RGB image to separate foreground from background and further working only on ROI

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I am working in a study involving images, the first step is to separate the foreground from background, and do further analysis only with foreground not involving background. Then later using the foreground image I have to find the median value of the foreground pixels then rectify the pixels based on a median value. So what I have done so far is first creating a transparent background, and storing the image using imwrite. Later I used the drawfreehand function to separate the ROI from the transparent background. Now I want to look at the ROI in the old RGB. I don't know how to do that, I am very new to MatLab kindly help with the code.

My updated code

```
img = im2double(imread('dkloriginalimgwithbcg.jpg')); 
himage = imshow(img);
ROI = drawfreehand
img_mask = createMask(ROI,img);
roi_img = img(img_mask);
%MedMask = median(roi_img);
dimg = img;             %must be double or single for this to work
dimg(~img_mask) = nan
%fun = @(B) median('(B(:)'); % median filter for mask
medimg = cast(dimg,'like',roi_img);% to get the mask to color image of face
himage = imshow(medimg); 
himage.AlphaData = medimg; % alpha layer usage to make the background transparent
OMed = median(medimg); % calculating median only inside the foreground not including background
imhist(medimg); 
histogram(roi_img,0:0.01:1);
total_median = median(medimage);
```

the error message is
Error setting property 'AlphaData' of class 'Image':
Value must be a scalar, vector or array of numeric or logical type

Error in alphaimgtrial1 (line 76)
himage.AlphaData = medimg; % alpha layer usage to make the background transparent

Comment: It's AlphaData, not AlphData. Also your code to calculate the median has unnecessary single quotes. It's assuming it's a string. Remove those.

Comment: Thanks, Ray, I changed the code like    
roi_img = img(img_mask);
dimg = img;             %must be double or single for this to work
dimg(~img_mask) = nan
medimg = cast(dimg,'like',roi_img);% to get the mask to color image of face
himage = imshow(medimg); 
medimg.AlphaData = medimg; % alpha layer usage to make the background transparent
 error Unable to perform assignment because dot indexing is not supported for variables of
this type.

Error in alphaimgtrial1 (line 76)
medimg.AlphaData = medimg; % alpha layer usage to make the background transparent

Comment: Please update your question. It's extremely difficult to read code in a comment.

Comment: Hi Ray, sorry for the error, I updated my new code.

Comment: I suspect it has something to do with the NaNs in your array.